# fdisk output is bold but no colors

Tags: linux, colors, fdisk

I have `gentoo`, `urxvt` terminal and `fdisk` shows no colors, but it does print some lines in **bold**

On some other machine the output is colorized

On both machines `ls` output is colorized

How I can also nice colors in my fdisk?

```
[ebuild   R    ] sys-apps/util-linux-2.26.2::gentoo  USE="cramfs ncurses nls pam python suid unicode -build -caps -fdformat (-selinux) -slang -static-libs -systemd {-test} -tty-helpers -udev" ABI_X86="32 (64) (-x32)" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python2_7 (-python3_3) -python3_4" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 (-python3_3) -python3_4" 0 KiB 
[ebuild   R   ] sys-apps/coreutils-8.23::gentoo  USE="nls -acl -caps -gmp -multicall (-selinux) -static -vanilla -xattr" 0 KiB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a file called `/etc/terminal-colors.d/fdisk.scheme` containing the colour scheme you desire (or copy it from another machine).

You may need to first create the `/etc/terminal-colors.d` directory (I had to on my debian machine - I had no idea until now that `fdisk` even had colour options...and now that I know, I don't want to know :-)

**NOTE:** Creating the file and the directory needs to be done as root (or with `sudo`).

For example, for an absolutely hideous, unreadable colour scheme, you might try:

```
header 33;41
help-title 34;43
warn 47;30
welcome 42;34
```

This is documented in the `fdisk` man page (search for the **COLORS** section near the bottom), and in the man page for `terminal-colors.d`.  The `fdisk` man page has this to say about colours:

> ```
> -L, --color[=when]
> ```
>
> Colorize  the  output.  The optional argument `when` can be `auto`, `never` or `always`.  If the `when` argument is omitted,
>   it defaults to `auto`.  The colors can be disabled; for the current built-in default see  the  `--help`  output.   See
>   also the **COLORS** section.

**NOTE**: if colours are disabled by default, you may also need to `sudo touch /etc/terminal-colors.d/fdisk.enable`.

and

> **COLORS**
>
> Implicit coloring can be disabled by an empty file `/etc/terminal-colors.d/fdisk.disable`.
>
> See `terminal-colors.d(5)` for more details about colorization configuration. The logical color names  supported  by  `fdisk`
>   are:
>
> ```
> header        The header of the output tables.
> help-title    The help section titles.
> warn          The warning messages.
> welcome       The welcome message.
> ```

`terminal-colors.d` seems to be a generic, centralised location for enabling, disabling, and or specifying colour schemes for a variety of command-line tools.  It's part of `util-linux` and is used by all tools within that package.  It may (or may not) have been adopted by other tools too.

I've never heard of it before today (not surprising, having garish colours on my terminal is not something that interests me) but it'll probably turn out to have been in existence for years.

Comment: I would think, that such file (maybe empy, just commented defaults) would be created on install, I was wrong. Now I need to came with decent colors :)

Comment: copy it from the other machine you mentioned which already has colourised output.   adjust to taste.  use my example as a warning of what not to do :)

Comment: The other machine also does not have it, but there is another version od fdisk, so different defaults

Answer (score 1):

You might like this custom color output for `fdisk -l`:

[image]

[Source:](https://gist.github.com/sebastiancarlos/27c96cf209919d4ad2d8b193945bc6f9)

```bash
### Add this to your .bashrc

# custom fdisk
# - add color when called with -l or -x
# - prepend sudo
function fdisk () {
  local green='\x1b[32m'
  local bold='\x1b[1m'
  local blue='\x1b[34m'
  local yellow='\x1b[33m'
  local reset='\x1b[0m'

  if [[ "$@" =~ -l|--list|-x|--list-details ]]; then
    command sudo fdisk --color=always "$@" | \
      sed -E -e 's/ ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)([A-Z]+) / '"${green}${bold}"'\1'"${reset}${green}"'\3'"${reset}"' /g' \
          -e 's/(^\/dev\/)([a-z0-9]+) /'"${blue}"'\1'"${reset}${bold}${blue}"'\2'"${reset}"' /g' \
          -e 's/(Disk )(\/dev\/)([a-z0-9]+): ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?) ([[:alpha:]]+),/\1'"${reset}${blue}"'\2'"${reset}${bold}${blue}"'\3'"${reset}${bold}"': '"${green}${bold}"'\4'"${reset}${green}"'\6'"${reset}${bold}"',/g' \
          -e 's/(Disk model: )(.*)/\1'"${reset}${yellow}"'\2'"${reset}"'/g' \
          -e 's/(Disklabel type: )(.*)/\1'"${reset}${yellow}"'\2'"${reset}"'/g'
  else
    command sudo fdisk --color=always "$@"
  fi
}
```